# React Native set image

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image

i want to have multiple cards of movies and shows for which i can set their name and image.
Everything works besides setting the image.

[MovieCard.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51zrT.png)

[Movies.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY5nP.png)

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVZNz.png)

I just started with react native yesterday so I'm sorry if my code is weird i'm relatively new to it haha :)

I tried implementing it the same way i did it for the shows name but that didn't work that well :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing 2 mistakes

1. App.js, you wrote "movieMap.Image" but in data "i" is small. So it should be "movieMap.image".
2. Movies.js, source prop of Image Tag isn't targeting the Image you passed from App.js. So change it to "source={props.ImageName}"